# save unknown number of images in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

a post may have no image or may have 10 images in the request so i dont know how to save them and here is my models

#### models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
     owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
     birthday = models.DateTimeField()

class PostImages(models.Model):
      owner = ForeignKey(Post)
      image = ImageField()
```

im going to save all of the images that are uploaded in POST.FILES so i tried:

```
for file in request.FILES:
    PostImages.objects.create(owner=post, image=file)
```

but file gives me a string and when i save it it have no filename extension i mean i cant use the file anymore because it has no type.i would like to use formsets but i don't know how to use it in this case or maybe i can't, i have no idea.

Comment: Have you read the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads ?

Comment: yes and it couldn't answer my question! @TomDalton

Comment: did you put the correct type into the form? u need something enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form. Then you need to extract that data from the POST. There should be plenty of tutorials on how to do that.

Comment: Yes it works perfectly and gets the files in `request.FILES`, i just need to save all the files in it with their names @ÖzerS.

Comment: yeah you should be able to find a tutorial on that. I had the same issue when I tried to save images in batch via javascript. If the files appear in your python view, then there is not much left. Not sure though how exactly, but search for something like "batch upload images django [javascript]"

Comment: so what youre basically missing is that the file name are converted to actual files. I think Django has some nice classes for that. Plus, the way you have an image in your example is wrong. You merely save the filename string, but you need to save the actual file. Something like `image = PostImages()`, `image.image.save(...)'

Comment: @ÖzerS. it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution

```
for img in request.FILES:
    PostImage.objects.create(owner = pst, image = request.FILES.get(img))
```

or

```
for img in request.FILES:
    pstimage = PostImage()
    pstimage.owner = pst
    pstimage.image = request.FILES.get(image)
    pstimage.save()
```